# "use strict" と ECMAScript6 の関係性について

Tags: ecmascript-6, javascript

**ECMAScript5 で、"use strict" 設定した際だけに起きる内容は、ECMAScript6 でも継続されるのでしょうか？** 
・例えば、関数呼出した際、「strictモードでは this が undefined になり、非strictモードではグローバルの this (ブラウザでは window)になる現象」は、継続されるのでしょうか？
・相変わらず明示的に"use strict" を付与しなければ、非strictモード状態でundefined にはならない？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) / ECMAScript 2016 でも Strict Mode の区別は継続します。
後方互換性のために、既存の振る舞いは変更できません。

ただ、後方互換性を考える必要が無い所はデフォルトで Strict Mode の振る舞いになります。
具体的には、

- Class 定義の内部
- Modules として読み込まれたコード全体

です。

### Class 定義の内部

```
class A {
    foo() {
        console.log("ここは Strict Mode です");
    }
}

console.log("ここは Strict Mode ではありません");

function foo() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("ここは Strict Mode です");
}
```

### Modules として読み込まれたコード全体

ブラウザでは、次のように `type="module"` として JavaScript コードを読み込むと、そのコードはモジュールとして扱われます。

```
<script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>
```

モジュールとして読み込まれたコードは、全体が強制的に Strict Mode になります。

---

See Also:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type